# Is there a way to Auto Login with VBA to an External Data Source in an Excel Workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

The title says it all. I have a workbook that I built a macro to automate, yet I can't get around manually entering the login in the middle of the Macro no matter what I try. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you show us the VBA code that you have tried?

Comment: You could check with the host to see if they have any API set up. The service that my company uses requires that all GET requests have the ID# and secret key attached. If there is no API, then you'll want to look into Selenium VBA and how to control a browser to navigate a webpage using VBA.

Comment: please provide some more info on where you are trying to login and some of your VBA code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.